# Different definitions of the first variation in calculus of variations

Tags: mathematical-physics, calculus-of-variations, classical-mechanics

In *Calculus of Variations* by Gelfand and Fomin the authors defined the variation $\delta J[h]$ of a functional $J[y]$ as the principle linear part of the increment $\Delta J[h]$:

$$\Delta J[h] = J[y+h] - J[y] = \delta J[h] + \epsilon(h) ||h||$$

where $\delta J[h]$ is a linear functional and $\epsilon(h) \rightarrow 0$ as $||h|| \rightarrow 0$.

I can now introduce an auxiliary variable $\alpha$ to calculate the variation as follows

\begin{align}
\Delta J[\alpha h] &= J[y+\alpha h] - J[y] \\
&= \delta J[\alpha h] + \epsilon(\alpha h) ||\alpha h|| \\
&= \alpha\delta J[h] + |\alpha|\epsilon(ah)||h||
\end{align}

Therefore,

$$ \frac{\partial J[y+\alpha h]}{\partial\alpha} = \delta J[h] + \operatorname{sgn}(\alpha) \epsilon(\alpha h)||h|| + |\alpha|\frac{\partial\epsilon(\alpha h)}{\partial\alpha} ||h||$$

The second and third term vanishe when $\alpha \rightarrow 0$, hence the variation

$$ \delta J[h] = \frac{\partial J[y+\alpha h]}{\partial\alpha} \bigg|_{\alpha \rightarrow 0} $$

However, in *Classical Mechenics* by Goldstein and *Classical Dynamics* by Thornton and Marion the variation is defined respectfully as

$$ \delta J = \frac{\partial J}{\partial\alpha} \bigg|_{\alpha = 0} d\alpha $$

and

$$ \delta J = \frac{\partial J}{\partial\alpha} d\alpha$$

So what is this $d\alpha$ that Goldstein, Thornton and Marion added to the partial derivative and does it make their definition of the variation any different from the one from Gelfand and Fomin?